# How can I use an iframe element as my header media?

Tags: headers, iframe

I am currently using the twenty-seventeen theme, which allows me to display a youtube video on the homepage and images on other pages.

Instead of a youtube video, I wish to display an iframe on the homepage in the header media. In WordPress' customise header menu I only have the option of entering a YouTube video url, or selecting an image

I have used the *inspect element* feature on my browser to replace the youtube video with the iframe in my browser and it looks perfect - how can I achieve this in the WordPress editor?

On Google, I've seen some vague posts about editing the theme etc, but nothing specific to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm happy to edit the PHP files but I'd need some pointers in the right direction, as I can't see anything useful in header.php.

Comment: It looks like it's mostly generated with JS in the `wp-custom-header` script but unfortunately, I can't find references to where that file is. It has help from the [`get_custom_header_markup()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_header_markup/) function. You might be better off just removing the header.php get_template_part and replacing it with your own.

Comment: Yes, and with Howdy, just want to remind you not to edit on the Twenty Seventeen theme files, but to [create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) to do the modifications.